# how to process all images on a folder with python

Tags: python

I have a python script to procces jpeg on a folder and overwrite the names after done

```
from PIL import Image, ImageOps,   JpegImagePlugin, ImageEnhance
#import jpegs from Repaired folder
im = Image.open('photo_2022-06-09_19-58-19.JPG')
# Crop
im = ImageOps.crop(im, border=17)
# Constract
im = ImageOps.autocontrast(im, cutoff = 1)
#sharpness
enhancer =     ImageEnhance.Sharpness(im).enhance(3)
im = ImageOps.posterize(im, bits=8)
#color
enhancer =      ImageEnhance.Color(im).enhance(3)
#save all jpegs and overwrite original file names
im.save("photo_2022-06-09_19-58-19.JPG", quality="maximum")
```

How can i process all jpeg files in that dir have a folder "repaired" and Overwrite the name of each processed file with the original file name?

Comment: You can read about [os](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) module, especially about [os.path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html)

Answer (score 1):

So it should be like this

```
import os
from PIL import Image, ImageOps,   JpegImagePlugin, ImageEnhance
#import jpegs from Repaired folder
for filename in os.listdir():
    if filename.endswith(".jpg"):
        im = Image.open(filename)
        # Crop
        im = ImageOps.crop(im, border=17)
        # Constract
        im = ImageOps.autocontrast(im, cutoff = 1)
        #sharpness
        enhancer =     ImageEnhance.Sharpness(im).enhance(3)
        im = ImageOps.posterize(im, bits=8)
        #color
        enhancer =      ImageEnhance.Color(im).enhance(3)
        #save all jpegs and overwrite original file names
        im.save(filename, quality="maximum")
    else:
        continue
```

Comment: Thank you, i have the main.py file  before that repaired jpeg to a folder named: repaired and i want to add this script to process all image file and overwrite that image name from original files

Comment: do you want to make programmatically process image files in folder and save to repaired folder with same name?

Comment: Ah image files have difference name by each files, yes that's right, the folder already name "repaired" have these jpeg so i wanf to automate them

Comment: can you try again i edited code

Answer (score 1):

I would use [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) and do something like this:

```py
import glob
from PIL import Image, ImageOps,   JpegImagePlugin, ImageEnhance

for fname in glob.glob('./repaired/*.JPG'):
    im = Image.open(fname)
    im = ImageOps.crop(im, border=17)
    im = ImageOps.autocontrast(im, cutoff = 1)
    enhancer = ImageEnhance.Sharpness(im).enhance(3)
    im = ImageOps.posterize(im, bits=8)
    enhancer =  ImageEnhance.Color(im).enhance(3)
    im.save(fname, quality="maximum")
```

You can print `fname` to see what it looks like, and process that string if you need to get the filename out, e.g. to write the file into a different folder.

Comment: Can i overwrite the files with name files before that after process it?

Comment: The code above will overwrite the file with the new data. Unless you're certain your code does what you want, this might be a bad idea. The string `fname` is the name of the file, with its full path. If you change it after reading the file with `Image.open()` and before the last line (`im.save()`), then you'll be writing a new file. You can change it with string processing, but the [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) module can be useful too.